# How to remove double URL reference in double foreach in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, foreach

So I've been working on a code in CodeIgniter, which requires a double foreach loop. This however is giving undesired results when I use the `site_url()` function that is provided. I've set it up in the config file so that it's being used properly, infact it works all over the site. The main issue that I am having is since it's a double foreach loop it's generating the site_url twice. so it's displaying it as `http://example.comhttp://example.com`.

The foreach loop is written as follows:

```
    <?php foreach($array1 as $key1): ?>
        <?php foreach($array2 as $key2): ?>
            <img src="<?= site_url() ?>" /> 
            // prints out "http://example.comhttp://example.com" in the img href
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The question is how do I get it so that it only displays `http://example.com` once and not generate the second one. I have to do this within the double foreach loop or the script won't work. I'm trying to figure out a work around this to prevent it from echoing the `site_url` out twice. Let me know if you're confused.

Comment: It's doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing - there are many ways to stop it echoing more than once, but to be of more help it's better if you could provide some context as to when you'd want to stop echoing - after just once? After a certain condition is met? etc.

Comment: I want it to print out each iteration of both foreach loop. I just want to prevent it from printing out he site_url a second time when it's within the second foreach loop. This is being use inside a `<img src="<?= site_url('image_path') ?>" />` so I want it to be able to print out all the images, but only want the url to show up once, and not twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty way to only echo the URL the once:

```
<?php 

$has_been_echoed = false;

?>
<?php foreach($array1 as $key1): ?>
    <?php foreach($array2 as $key2): ?>
        <?php if($has_been_echoed == false){ echo site_url(); $has_been_echoed = true; } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

To echo the site_url() just once within each *second* loop, try it this way:

```
<?php 

$has_been_echoed = false;

?>
<?php foreach($array1 as $key1): ?>
    <?php foreach($array2 as $key2): ?>
        <?php if($has_been_echoed == false){ echo site_url(); $has_been_echoed = true; } ?>
    <?php

    endforeach;

    $has_been_echoed = false;

    ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: see the updated code, it's used for an img src. Will this method still work? - EDIT: I need it to print out for each of the images, but only once for each of the image src's

Comment: I'd suggest trying it and see if it's what you're after, I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what you're trying to achieve. This will loop though properly but only ever echo out the site_url() once.

Comment: The goal of this is to achieve something like this screenshot. The code that generates it is a double foreach loop and the broken images is within the second foreach loop. http://puu.sh/26kEB